# $i=\ln((-1)^{\frac{1}{\pi}})$

Tags: complex-numbers

I tried finding another definitions of $i$ simplifying the Euler Identity $e^{i\pi}+1=0$

I followed this steps:

**1.** $(e^i)^\pi = -1$

**2.** $e^i = (-1)^{\frac{1}{\pi}}$

**3.** $i = \ln((-1)^{\frac{1}{\pi}})$

**4.** $i = \frac{\ln(-1)}{\pi}$

Is it right?

Comment: No it is not right at all, and your first faulty step is 2.: there is no canonical univalued function $z\mapsto z^{1/\pi}$ on $\mathbb C$ (only on $\mathbb R_+$). Step 3. is faulty as well.

Comment: What do you mean by another definition? What definition do you have for $i$?

Comment: Why step 2 is faulty?

Comment: For the reason explained just after  `:` in my first comment.

Comment: I don't get it because if $x^y=z$ then $x=z^\frac{1}{y}$

Comment: How do you define $z^{1/y}$? For example, $(-1)^{1/2}$? You would find $i^2=-1$ as well as $(-i)^2=-1$, and there is no other $z$ satisfying $z^2=-1$, so it's reasonable to say $(-1)^{1/2}=i,-i$. Unfortunately, the same is _not_ true for $(-1)^{1/\pi}$. There are _infinitely_ many $z$ satisfying $z^\pi=-1$, and in fact such $z$ is dense on the unit circle. So $(-1)^{1/\pi}$ is poorly defined, and your statement does not make much sense.

Comment: Usually the principal branch of logarithm has a branch cut along the negative real axis, so $\log -1$ is undefined.

Comment: OP: Please learn to use @.

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/title-and-latex). BTW Did's comment above refers to [comment replies](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/comment-replies/info).